# Apache 2.4 and Alias at /tmp

Tags: apache

If I leave a.txt file at /home/myuser and at /tmp and I configure the default host in apache 2.4 like this:

```
Alias /a1 /tmp
<Directory /tmp>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /a2 /home/myuser
<Directory /home/myuser>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then I am able to do:

```
  wget http://localhost/a2/a.txt
```

but not:

```
 wget http://localhost/a1/a.txt
```

Is there anything special with /tmp regarding to apache 2.4?

Comment: Does the user that run your Apache have full access to /tmp?  When you try .../a1/a.txt, what does it do?  404?  What do the logs say?  Change `LogLevel debug` and try again to get full logs.

Comment: Yes. If I do sudo -u www-data cat /tmp/a.txt it shows the content of that file

Comment: Without more configuration or logs we cannot do much to help, as this configuration should work, I just tried it on my system.

Comment: I've changed LogLevel to trace8, and the only interesting line (the rest say request authorized) is the one which says "AH00128: File does not exist".

@Nic3500, in which OS version have you tried? Me in Kubuntu 18.04 and now again in a Debian 9. The same behaviour

Comment: Linux Mint 18.3.  We will need to see your configuration, there has to be something else in the configuration than what you posted causing a problem here.  Make the /tmp/a.txt exists and has proper permissions.